# Error con Ajax en Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ajax

estoy intentando actualizar el valor de un registro en función del estado de un check pero siempre me salta error en el success, adjunto codigos:

Input check:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check_disponible" {{ $data->active ? 'checked' : ''}} data-width="150" data-id="{{$data->id}}" data-toggle="toggle"data-on="Disponible"  data-off="No disponible" data-size="mini">
```

Ajax:

```
$(".check_disponible").on('change', e=> {
      var id = $(e.target).data('id');
          var checked = $(e.target).prop('checked');
           var estado = checked ? 1 : 0;
           var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
          console.log("Estado:"+estado+ " id: "+id+" token:"+token );
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('changeActive')}}",
            type:'post',
            data:{
                  _token:token,
                  id:id,
                  estado: estado
            },
            success:data => {
                       toastr.success('Se ha llevado a cabo el cambio de disponibilidad.');
                  },
                    error:data => {
                       toastr.error('No se ha podido llevar a cabo el cambio de estado de la solicitud.');
                   }
        });
    });
```

Ruta:

```
Route::post(
'/change-active',
'Admin\UserEmployeeController@CambioDisponible')->name('changeActive');
```

Controlador:

```
  public function CambioDisponible(Request $request){
  $user_employee = UsersEmployee::where('id', $request->id)->first();
  $user_employee->active =  $request->estado ;
    if ($user_employee->save()) {
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Todo ok']);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Error Processing save", 1);
    }
}
```

El registro que busca el controlador existe siempre dada la id, pero no se qué está fallando.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué error te dá?

Comment: Salta el toast  error:data => { toastr.error('No se ha podido llevar a cabo el cambio de estado de la solicitud.'); y tampoco modifica el valor en la bbdd

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un `console.log(data);` para ver de qué se trata el error? O revisa en las herramientas para desarrollador la pestaña de red, la que apunta a la url del ajax.

Comment: creo que tu error esta aquí ***url: "{{route('changeActive')}}",*** intenta de esta manera ***url: 'changeActive',***